# Tic tac toe linked list insert

Tags: c++

Any idea how can i make a tic tac toe using full linked list? My first idea was creating this

```
struct Node
{
 int data;
 Node*next,*prev,*up,*down;
}
```

Then I'll make a Linked List class like the usual double Linked List with class member head and tail. But usually they only linked next and prev. The problem is how can i make each data access the up and down node. How can i link them all dynamically? Not initializing them one by one
When player 1 insert index 1, then suddenly jump to 5...how the linked list should be?
Should I use multiple linked list? If yes, how does the logic goes? Thanks!

```
void sortedInsert(struct Node** head_ref, struct Node* newNode) 
{ 
    struct Node* current; 
  
    // if list is empty 
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
        *head_ref = newNode; 
  
    // if the node is to be inserted at the beginning 
    // of the doubly linked list 
    else if ((*head_ref)->data >= newNode->data) { 
        newNode->next = *head_ref; 
        newNode->next->prev = newNode; 
        *head_ref = newNode; 
    } 
  
    else { 
        current = *head_ref; 
  
        // locate the node after which the new node 
        // is to be inserted 
        while (current->next != NULL &&  
               current->next->data < newNode->data) 
            current = current->next; 
  
        /* Make the appropriate links */
        newNode->next = current->next; 
  
        // if the new node is not inserted 
        // at the end of the list 
        if (current->next != NULL) 
            newNode->next->prev = newNode; 
  
        current->next = newNode; 
        newNode->prev = current; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does a linked list have to do with tic tac toe? And how does inserting or removing something in such a linked list accomplish the goal of implementic tic tac toe? I think you're misunderstanding your homework assignment or a problem, and you should ask your instructor for clarification.

Comment: Your approach for such a "2d linked list" for Tic Tac Toe is very strange. (This may add an extra burden for whatever you have to achieve.) If your homework is about Tic Tac Toe then I would go with a 2d array. If your homework is about a nice application of a linked list, then another application might be more appropriate: A sparse matrix, a map for an adventure like game, or (where I saw list nodes like yours in action) a fast AABB pre-test for real-time collision detection.

Comment: Just use 2D array with very big dimensions - like `std::array<std::array<Field, 100>. 100> a;` when Field could be `enum class Field { Empty, Player1, Player2 };`  I would be very surprised 100x100 is not enough for this game.